# Request permissions to submit my app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, permissions, publish

I'm trying to get Publish_permission for my app and I've submitted my app three times, but there's a problem and it is that when trying to publish a post using facebook, the app crashes when it tries to request the Publish_permission. The app was working and posting, but when I submmited it the first time, it stopped working and now I get a nullpointerexception when publishing.

private void publishStory(String mensaje) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

```
    if (session != null){

        // Check for publish permissions 

        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                    .NewPermissionsRequest(new SocialActivity(), PERMISSIONS);
//************The next line is where the exception occurs***********************
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

            return;
        }
```

I don't know if I changed something on facebook developers that made my app stop working. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What exception are you seeing?

Comment: A nullpointerexception at session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest); apparentely newPermission is null, I'm assuming that I need permissions granted by Facebbok but they can't test my app if it is not working, so what should I do? Thanks